# Allow user to select a column and use the column as a reference point

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to allow the user to select a column through the application input, in order for me to be able to use the column as a reference point. However, have the following issues with my code;

**Issues**

- My code doesn't force the user to select a column, rather it selects a single cell.
- I can't seem to then reference a particular cell in the column. For example, if the user chose column A and the transaction column, if i wanted to sum all positive values in column A.

```
Dim UserInput1 As Range 'Transaction Column Identifier
Dim Transaction_Column As Range 'Transaction Column

'Error Handling
On Error Resume Next

'Allows the user to select location of Transaction Amount Column
Set UserInput1 = Application.InputBox _
        (prompt:="Choose the Transaction Amount Column", Type:=8)
   
'Error Handling to ensure user does not select more than 1 column
If UserInput1.Columns.Count <> 1 Then
    MsgBox ("Please Select One Column")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to check if a user selected an entire column, including checking the `.Cells.Count`.

```
If UserInput1.Columns.Count <> 1 Or UserInput1.Cells.Count <> UserInput1.EntireColumn.Cells.Count Then
```

Comment: I have done the above, in order to check the user has not selected a range across multiple columns. However, is there a way to force the user to select a column, i.e. not have the option to select a single cell

Comment: Not natively with `Application.InputBox` but the above check should work.

Comment: This makes sense, for part 2 of the Question. If the user select column A, how am i then able to reference that column in my VBA script. For example, if i wanted to sum the column or sum a certain range within the column

Comment: Use `WorksheetFunction.Sum` to sum, or use `.Range` or `.Cells` to refer to certain cells within the column.

Comment: I don't think this works. For example if the user selected column G, how do i use the `UserInput1` definition to select `G2`

Comment: `UserInput1.Cells(2)`

Comment: Ahh i see!! may you give me an example of how i would use `.Range` and `WorksheetFunction.Sum`

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.Sum(UserInput1)`? `UserInput1.Range("A2")`? Not sure what you want to do.